# Ripple requires API level 21 (current min is 11), android?

Tags: android, material-design, floating, ripple

I have the below drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And I am getting this error

```
<ripple> requires API level 21 (current min is 11)
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using minsdk=11.

You can't use this drawable with api<21.

**You have to use diffent versions** of this drawable file.
Put this code in  `res/drawable-v21/myRipple.xml` and create a different `res/drawable/myRipple.xml`

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that the  tag was added in API 21, RippleDrawable is pretty simple and it's possible to port it back to API 1. There's a good number of libraries backporting the ripple for older devices. For a sample implementation see:

https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/drawable/ripple/RippleDrawableICS.java

Comment: updated - the file was there, but was changed since March

Comment: Fixed. Froyo is no longer supported